# Aurelia: Error: Attempted to register an Element when one with the same name already exists. Name: n. - Only occurs in production webpack build

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I recently split my webpack builds into separate config files and merge them with a common one.

The only difference between the configurations besides the `mode` is a globally defined `BASE_URL`

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack').DefinePlugin;
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new DefinePlugin({
            BASE_URL: JSON.stringify('http://localhost:5000')
        })
    ]
})
```

Prior to doing this, I was using a single webpack.config and the `--mode production` option from the CLI.

In my code, I can see the proper `BASE_URL` in both bundles, but only the `development` one works; the other throws the error: `Error: Attempted to register an Element when one with the same name already exists. Name: n.` which is very unhelpful, since I don't have an element with the name of `n`.

EDIT: The error appears to be occuring during the autoregistration of global resources, specifically, for this my `DateFormat` value converter:

date-format.ts

```
export class DateFormatValueConverter {
    toView(value: string) {
        return new Date(value).toLocaleString();
    }
}
```

index.ts

```
import { FrameworkConfiguration } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { DateInputFormatValueConverter } from './value-converters/date-input-format';
import { DateFormatValueConverter } from './value-converters/date-format';

export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
    config.globalResources(
        [
            DateInputFormatValueConverter,
            DateFormatValueConverter
        ]
    )
}
```

EDIT2: It appears to be anything that is resourced globally, except for the first entry.

EDIT3: It seems that if I declare global resources via strings (and `PLATFORM.moduleName`) works. This may be something the Aurelia team should look into.

```
export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
    config.globalResources(
        [
            PLATFORM.moduleName('./value-converters/date-input-format'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('./value-converters/date-format'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('./value-converters/delay-format'),
            ...
        ]
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the class name got mangled into 1-2 letters. like this:

```
export class DatePicker {}
// turned into
// when inspecting the class for static resources declaration, name of the resource will be "n"
let n = class{}
exports.DatePicker = n;
```

The fix is to give them explicit name:

```
// either
@customElement('date-picker')
// or
export class DatePicker {
  static $resource = {
    name: 'date-picker',
    type: 'element'
  }
  // if it's custom element, no need to specify type
  static $resource = 'date-picker';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out an accept the answer once verified!